# ¿por que me sale permiso denegado al ejecutar un ejecutable desde un script en python?

Tags: python

Hola buenas estoy tratando de hacer un script en python que me ejecute un ejecutable, en este caso firefox. luego que me lo ejecute iba a pasar el script a un ejecutable para poder ejecutar firefox con solo un click.

el problema es que al ejecutar el script me aparece esto:

```
sh: 1: ./firefox: Permission denied
```

y cuando ejecuto firefox desde la terminal si me lo ejecuta perfectamente.

este es el codigo:

```
from os import system

system("cd /home/josech/firefox/")
system("./firefox")
```

Estoy utilizando una distro basada en debian.

De antemano muchas gracias!!!.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se mucho de linux, pero en linux, el usuario que ejecuta la terminal es el mismo usuario que trata de ejecutar el programa desde python?

Comment: intenta darte permisos 7777 al script y a ./firefox o ejecutar el script con sudo

Answer (score 1):

No es muy claro la razón de tu error. Podrían ser por muchas cosas, y algo que te ayudaría sería:

1. Estar seguro de que de verdad quieras ejecutar ese archivo. Tal vez no lo puedes ejecutar porque no es un ejecutable, y se le omitieron los permisos de ejecución cuando se creó, o quizás ese programa lo quieres correr, pero se corre mediante un wrapper
2. Ver si tiene permisos de ejecución en general y también para el usuario que corre el programa en python

Esto lo puedes ver dando un: `ls -la <ruta>` hacía la ruta completa del archivo al que quieres dar ejecución.

Las letras "x'" te dirán quién tiene permisos para ejecutarlo.

Ya luego, sabiendo qué permisos tienes, sabrás si puedes modificar estos con `chmod` o con `chown`. O usar `groupadd` para agregar tu usuario a algún grupo que pueda ejecutarlo.